# Could not open input file: in cmd

Tags: php

i run this code in CMD

```
D:\AppServ\php5\php.exe D:\AppServ\www\test\items.php?id=1
```

but i got this error

> Could not open input file: D:\AppServ\www\test\items.php?id=1

if i remove `?id=1` its work but i need all link part
how to fix and run in comand prompt

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: `?` is for parameters in URLs going through a webserver. They have no special meaning in CLI.

Comment: no way to used in command line ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Command Line Arguments and Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043775/php-command-line-arguments-and-options)

Answer (score 0):

**?** doesn't work in cli mode.

For Cli the parameters are passed just like for another shell script:

```
D:\AppServ\php5\php.exe D:\AppServ\www\test\items.php id=1
```

Anything that follows after the script is sent to php as parameter.