# Passing an argument to a file in linux

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I was wondering if there was some way to pass an argument to a file when running it.  For example, I am running a php file in Linux called createcsv.php which uses two MySQL tables, an old one named products_feburary and a new one named products_march.  It then generates csv files with data that is in the March catalog and not in the Feburary one.  Right now, when the month changes I would change the MySQL tabels by simply editing the files and changing products_feburary -> products_march and products_march -> products_april.  I am simply wondering if there was some way to pass the MySQL tables to the file directly something like createcsv.php("products_feburary", "products_march") which would allow me to pass the months as paremeters without needing to edit the files.  Note that, the names are stored as strings so I only need to pass them as text.  I have tried researching this, but haven't found anything on the internet that indicates that this is possible.  I am wondering if there is a way to do this or a package you can install that allows you to do this.

Update:  Unfortunately, I had not seen the [PHP Command Line Arguments and Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043775/php-command-line-arguments-and-options) question.  To make my question more specific and separate it from the other question, I am wondering for a nonexpert, if someone could give an example of code for how exactly to pass the argument in the command line and receive it in the file using either the $argv or getopt() methods.  Based on the second answer, it seems you pass it as

```
php createcsv.php products_feburary products_march
```

but within the file I am having trouble with receiving the arguments in a way such as

```
$oldtable = (assign "products_feburary")
$newtable = (assign "products_march")
```

I am wondering if someone can provide a small Hello World type program that shows how to read the inputs from the $argv or getopt() methods.

Comment: `./when you run a program` the program `when` is run and it receives the arguments "you", "run", "a", "program" as arguments. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043877/2067492) gives you a very concise example of what php does with the arguments.

Comment: Usually in PHP-CLI, one would first ask:  `if (is_array($argv)) { ... } else {echo $usage;}`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php