# "Hardcode" passed variables from JQuery/Javascript into a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, variables, parameter-passing, hardcode

I am creating an *E-mail Reporting System* to send scheduled e-mails (daily, weekly, etc.) with the results of certain `SQL` queries.

I have one `HTML` & `JQuery` page, **generate.html**, containing a form which allows a user to customize the report. The form enables the user to change certain variables of the `SQL` query to be executed.

These variables are passed to a `PHP` file, **report.php**, which contains the queries and handles e-mailing the results.

### For Example

A user inputs an e-mail address on the `HTML` form and submits. **report.php** receives this variable through `$input_email = trim($_REQUEST['input_email']);`.

My problem lies in using `cron` to execute the **report.php** file on a scheduled basis. I have not tried it, but I am pretty sure that when `cron` executes **report.php**, it will see `$input_email` in the `PHP` file and not know what to do with it.

### I see two solutions

1. Have `cron` not execute just `report.php`, but **report.php** with the added query string, so it looks like: `report.php?input_email=user@email.com`
2. Duplicate the **report.php** file into a new file, **hardcode.php**, where all the `$variables` are replaced with their actual values, and then `cron` can just execute `hardcode.php` on it's own

I wish to implement the ***second*** solution, but cannot figure out how. I am relatively new to PHP and JQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: $argv[1] is your first command line argument, so if you block of the assignment of input_email so it's something like `if(isset($argv[1]))  $_REQUEST["input_email"] = $argv[1];` then you can call it via `php report.php user@email.com`

Comment: This may help you [Passing $_GET parameters to cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297945/passing-get-paramaters-to-cron-job) You can pass the variables in the cmd line for the cron setup.

Comment: Great idea, I'll have to play around with it. You can have multiple cron jobs for the same file, using different parameters for each job, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not

> > 1. insert all values sent into a database
> > 2. retrieve all values in a new email.php file and run a loop that sends all reports?

That sounds like a solution to me and you can cron the email.php file

Comment: This is also a great idea... although I would imagine it would be slightly more expensive with all the extra database calls. I'll have to think about the best solution.