# passing previous day to crontab argument

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have some php script i want to run every day at 5AM. This script works with `$_GET['datevar']`

I would like to create cronjob to call following script

```
var/www/somedir/myscript.php&datevar='previous_day'
```

Where previous day means "yesterday".

I've heard about arguments like :

```
var/www/somedir/myscript.php datevar='previous_day'
```

but i cant make it work.

previous day has to be in format *"yyyy-mm-dd"*

Can anybody provide me some hint?

Comment: show the full intended crontab record related with that script execution

Comment: Take a look at this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297945/passing-get-paramaters-to-cron-job


In short, $_GET and $_POST are not populated when you use crontab.