# PHP cron job with php parameters

Tags: php, cron, parameter-passing

Hello i have following script that i want to execute :

```
30 12 * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/dev/create_report.php type=NR date=$(date +\%Y\%m\%d --date='2 days')
```

But im still getting following messages :

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 18
enter code here`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: date in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 28
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 30
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 30

PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 31
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 31
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 41
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 89
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 89
```

Can anybody help me please ? Im getting sick of this.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE #1
code of create_report.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
//PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
// pripojenie sa k dtb
$mysqli = new mysqli('192.168.0.20', 'mfric', 'mFRIC6389mf', 'asterisk');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
switch ($_GET['type']){
    case 'BB' : $typ = "Banska_Bystrica";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWEBB%' or campaign_id like 'RWEAKVBB';");break;
    case 'TN' : $typ = "Trencin";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWETN%';");break;
    case 'NR' : $typ = "Nitra";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWENR%';");break;
    //case 'ZA' : $typ = "Liptovsky_Mikulas";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWEZA_RK' or campaign_id like 'RWEZA_LM';");break;
    case 'ZAA' : $typ = "Zilina";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWEZA%' or campaign_id like 'RWEZA_LM' or campaign_id like 'RWEZA_RK';");break;
    case 'TT' : $typ = "Trnava";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWETT%';");break;        
    case 'BA' : $typ = "Bratislava";$result =mysqli_query($mysqli, "select tabulka from creator_db where campaign_id like 'RWEBA%';");break;        
    default : $typ = "N/A";
}
$datum=$_GET['date'];
$datum2=explode("-",$datum);
$datum_c2 = $datum2[2].".".$datum2[1].".".$datum2[0];
$datum_sheetname = $datum2[0].$datum2[1].$datum2[2];
// inicializacia objektu
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
//nastavenie parametrov 
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("eCall Slovakia");
//$objPHPExcel->setLastModifiedBy("eCall Slovakia");
//$objPHPExcel->setTitle("eCall Slovakia - report RWE AUDIT NR");
//$objPHPExcel->setSubject("eCall Slovakia - report RWE AUDIT NR");
// inicializacia "sheetu" prveho
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('RWE audit '.$_GET['type'].' '.$datum_sheetname);
//nastavenie rowcount na = 1 / zacinam prvym riadkom;
$rowCount = 5;
//nastavenie autosize na vsetky stlpce
foreach(range('D','Q') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}
foreach(range('A','B') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')
        ->setWidth('15');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')
        ->setWidth('17')
        ->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')
        ->setWidth('10')
        ->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')
        ->setWidth('15')
        ->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')
        ->setWidth('15')
        ->setAutoSize(false);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1',"eCall Slovakia / RWE - audit - report zaujmov");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A2',"Dátum : ".$datum_c2);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A4',"IMK");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B4',"Okres");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C4',"Telefónne číslo");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D4',"Meno");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E4',"Priezvisko");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F4',"Ulica");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G4',"Číslo");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H4',"Mesto");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I4',"PSČ");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J4',"Poschodie");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K4',"Kontakt pre audítora");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L4',"Volal agent - osobné číslo");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M4',"Volal - dátum");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N4',"Dátum stretnutia:");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O4',"Čas stretnutia:");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P4',"email");
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q4',"Poznámky");
//nacitanie databaz a nasledne vytiahnutie potrebnych dat
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    $pole[$i] = $row['tabulka'];
    $i++;
   }
$pocet = $i;
mysqli_close($mysqli);
$mysqli = new mysqli('192.168.0.20', 'mfric', 'mFRIC6389mf', 'asterisk');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
for($j=0;$j<$pocet;$j++){
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from ".$pole[$j]." join vicidial_list on ".$pole[$j].".lead_id=vicidial_list.lead_id where (vicidial_list.status='ZP1' or vicidial_list.status='NZX') and left(".$pole[$j].".au_datum_a_stretnutie,10)='".$datum."';");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
    $okres = str_replace("Bánska","Banská",$row['slct_okres']); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['slct_kraj']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,$okres);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,$row['tel']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,$row['meno']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,$row['priezvisko']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount,$row['ulica']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,$row['popisne_cislo']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount,$row['mesto']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount,$row['psc']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,$row['au_poschodie']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount,$row['au_kontakt_kv']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount,$row['kod_predajcu']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount,$row['last_local_call_time']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$rowCount,$row['au_datum_a_stretnutie']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$rowCount,$row['au_cas_a_stretnutie']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P'.$rowCount,$row['email']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q'.$rowCount,$row['poznamka_klient']);
    $rowCount++;
   }
}

// stylovanie ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:Q4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);


$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'allborders' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_DOTTED
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5:Q'.($rowCount-1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => false,
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size'  => 11,
        'name'  => 'Calibri'
    )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5:Q'.($rowCount-1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size'  => 11,
        'name'  => 'Calibri'
    )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:Q4')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size'  => 16,
        'name'  => 'Arial'
    )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'font'  => array(
        'bold'  => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size'  => 14,
        'name'  => 'Arial'
    )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'left' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A5:A'.($rowCount-1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'right' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Q5:Q'.($rowCount-1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$styleArray = array(
  'borders' => array(
    'bottom' => array(
      'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
    )
  )
);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.($rowCount-1).':Q'.($rowCount-1))->applyFromArray($styleArray);
unset($styleArray);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('M5:M50')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('yyyy-mm-dd');
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("rwe/report/eCall Slovakia - RWE - audit -  ".$typ." - report - zaujmy - ".$datum_sheetname.".xlsx" );
// ODOSIELANIE EMAILOM
$yourName = 'TEST';
$yourEmail_2 = 'martina.lunzerova@ecallslovakia.sk';
ini_set("include_path", "Classes/PHPMailer");
require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = 'rwereport@ecallslovakia.sk';
$mail->FromName = 'eCall Slovakia - RWE';
$mail->AddAddress($yourEmail_2);
$mail->AddCC('martin.fric@ecallslovakia.sk');
//$mail->AddCC('katarina.kralova@ecallslovakia.sk');
$mail->AddAttachment("rwe/report/eCall Slovakia - RWE - audit -  ".$typ." - report - zaujmy - ".$datum_sheetname.".xlsx", "eCall Slovakia - RWE - audit -  ".$typ." - report - zaujmy - ".$datum_sheetname.".xlsx");
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                              // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true);  
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                             // send as HTML
$mail->Subject  =  'RWE - audit - report zaujmov - '.$typ.' '.$datume_sheetname;
$mail->Body     =  'Dobrý deň,<br/><br/>v prilohe Vám zasielame report záujmov z telemarketingovej kampane RWE<br/>-⁠ audit, ktorý je spracovávaný spoločnosťou eCall Slovakia.<br/><br/>Mesto:Nitra<br/>Na dátum:'.$datum_sheetname.'<br/></br>S pozdravom,<br/>';
//$mail->AltBody  =  'Dobrý deň,<br/><br/>v prilohe Vám zasielame report záujmov z telemarketingovej kampane RWE<br/>-⁠ audit, ktorý je spracovávaný spoločnosťou eCall Slovakia.<br/><br/>Mesto:Nitra<br/>Na dátum:'.$datum_sheetname.'<br/></br>S pozdravom,<br/>';

if ( $mail->Send()){
   ?><script>alert('Mail bol odoslany');</script><?
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE #2

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 10
array(3) {
  ["/var/www/dev/create_report.php"]=>
  NULL
  ["type"]=>
  string(2) "NR"
  ["date"]=>
  string(10) "2016-06-25"
}
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 24
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: date in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 34
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 36
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 36
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 37
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 37
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 47
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 95
PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 95
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file rwe/report/eCall Slovakia - RWE - audit -  N/A - report - zaujmy - .xlsx.' in /var/www/dev/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:389
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/dev/create_report.php(244): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('rwe/report/eCal...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/dev/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 389
```

UPDATE #3

```
    <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<$argc; $i++){//iterate over one parameter at a time
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $argv[$i]);//explode parameter at =
    $parameter[$key]=$val;//make kvp pair in $parameter
}

var_dump($parameter);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
//PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
// pripojenie sa k dtb
$mysqli = new mysqli('192.168.0.20', 'mfric', 'mFRIC6389mf', 'asterisk');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

...

Comment: How are you retrieving the values?

Comment: Hello, in create_report.php using $_GET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing $\_GET paramaters to cron job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297945/passing-get-paramaters-to-cron-job)

Comment: If you really want to get this debug, you have to share the code of create_report.php file.

Comment: i dont understand what they mean in there. I found here this solution but it just wont work. Should i change $_GET method to something else?

Comment: i have added create_report.php

Comment: Check in ur variable **$datum_c2** is a resutls some wrong date, try `echo` in a look correct or not?! i think a type de date wrong

Comment: datum_c2 is ok. i just need to pass values to my script using cron

Answer (score 1):

Check how you retreive the cli arguments, passed to the php script.

For testing purpose add this to your script:

```
var_dump($argc); //will print number of arguments passed 
var_dump($argv); //argument itself
```

Then add a "logging" to your cron table.

```
30 12 * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/dev/create_report.php type=NR date=$(date +\%Y\%m\%d --date='2 days') &>/home/your_user/cron.log
```

This way the output will be written to `/home/your_user/cron.log` and you will see what is passed as argument.

To actually get the values I would run over the `$argc` counter and explode the values on `=` to get a kvp pair.

```
list($key, $val) = explode('=', $argv[1]);
var_dump(array($key=>$val));
```

**for your Update #1**

Your script contains html and php code. So when you call your script with `php /var/www/dev/create_report.php` it will always output the html code unterpreted. Think about that and if you really want it this way. Outputting html code to cli is pretty ugly. But it's possbile. What's broken with your code is the `$_GET` usage. This won't work in cli scripts as I mentioned above.

```
$parameter = []; //create a array that will hold parameter
for($i=1; $i<$argc; $i++){//iterate over one parameter at a time
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $argv[$i]);//explode parameter at =
    $parameter[$key]=$val;//make kvp pair in $parameter
}

var_dump($parameter);
```

This will show

```
**array(2) {
  'type' =>
  string(2) "NR"
  'date' =>
  string(8) "20160625"
}**
```

Now you can access your cli parameter as you want. Just use `$datum=$parameter['date'];` instead of `$datum=$_GET['date'];`

Comment: I have no contetnt in my cron.log

Comment: Please also show the new code as there is no access to array key `1` in line 10 as your error indicates.

Comment: My fault, the for loop stats at `1` not `0`. However these errors `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /var/www/dev/create_report.php on line 24` are still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is intended to be run via web, consider using something like `wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/create_report.php?type=NR` for the cron (instead of `php create_report.php`) and use PHP date()/time() in your script as input instead of relying on date/timestamp from shell. It will be much easier to test directly via web.

And please remove the login details in your script.

Comment: its locally and it is fake :)